# How important is setting environment variables in Java?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I am writing a blog where I have explain my students how to install Java, but I'm wondering why should expose them to this complicated part of Java installation. When I used Java before, I used right out of the box with my IDE. But all the tutorials I see mention configuration of these environment variables.

Maybe my PATH variables were set from previous installations, however I don't remember doing it.

Can anyone please advise if environment variable setting can be left to the IDEs or has to be done manually?

Comment: Just a thought, if you don't remember you can use a virtual machine that doesn't have Java installed, then record your steps.

Comment: More often than not you don't need to set them. Or they get installed during the installation process. Most often they get used to resolve problems so being aware of what they are and what they do is useful if something goes wrong.

Comment: @Developer I'm not sure if the environment variables get uninstalled, why do all blogs mention them.. I feel like it's such an ancient thing..

Answer (score 6):

Java does not need any environment variables to be set.

However, setting some environment variables makes some things easier.

- `PATH` If the `jre/bin` folder is on the path, you don't have to qualify to run the `java` command. If the `jdk/bin` folder is on the path, you don't have to qualify to run the `java` and `javac` commands. As well as some other commands provided by Java.
- `JAVA_HOME` Used by many Java programs and installers to find Java.

When using an IDE, it can usually find / prompt for Java installations, so it doesn't need any environment variables. The IDE won't set them either.

Comment: But the IDE doesn't need them while running a program - when you first install Java then IDE (rather than installing the platform from within the IDE).

Comment: Besides, I'm pretty sure nobody uses manual java and javac commands

Comment: @NavinIsrani sure we do! Just like how you can make C++ manually with g++. Some of my console Java programs even run faster than my console C++ programs when I implement the same algorithms!

Comment: But such projects are very rare - at least in the enterprise. And for my purpose i.e. teach undergrad students, IDE based execution is enough. Only one program of manual execution is usually taken.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, `JAVA_HOME` Used by many Java programs and installers to locate Java. for instance, Tomcat requires the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to be set to the JDK installed directory.

To check if `JAVA_HOME` is already set, start a terminal and issue:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

`JAVA_HOME` is to be set to the JDK installed directory. You need to find your JDK installed directory.

**[TODO]** find macOS and Ubuntu JDK installed directory.

Add the the following line at the end of `"~/.bashrc"` (or `"~/.login"`). Take note that filename beginning with dot (.) is hidden by default.

**[TODO]** How to un-hide for macOS/Ubuntu.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/JDK-installed-directory


// Verify the new setting
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Java and then installed Eclipse, and you know what, it worked fine, however for one of my colleagues it was giving a "warning" regarding not being able to find Java, and error was clearly showing it needs environment variables because it wasn't able to find the path to Java, like Java wasn't installed, while it was installed there.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's more like commentary, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30137673)

Comment: well, I can't add a comment dear, so that's why added answer.